# Rails 3 Check to see if an email address is real

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3

i want to check to see if a given email say for example (yourname@your_domain.com) most likely that exact email don't exist is there a way to ping the email address or anything along that along that idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the address format is valid, but there is no effective, email-specific "Ping" or lookup that you can do, other then sending a verification e-mail containing a code or link which the users clicks on or enters on your site to verify their address.

Comment: i thought i seen something like that in java script tho. I have been wrong before tho lol

Comment: @Rod Nelson, that's probably because this answer is technically incorrect but practically correct. You can "ping" on the transport layer, but it's unreliable and a security risk so in the real world it might as well not exist.

Answer (score 7):

You can't reliably verify email addresses without human intervention. That's why the most common method is to send the user a 'confirmation' email.

Comment: i was just looking for an easy way to keep out fake names and bots i have the site written in PHP ATM and i delete about 20 bots a day manually

Answer (score 7):

You can use my gem: "email_verifier" that you can find here: https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier

It gives you validator which connects with given mail server "asking" smtp server if there is given email address.

Comment: cool! This checks an actual email address's existence, and not just the domain name?

Comment: It does not appear to. khq4ljt3qjhbf@yahoo.com is not a real address, but it returns valid from the gem

Comment: From looking at the code it appears this just checks the domain name?